# Add returned LINQ result to label/textbox

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, label, return, code-behind

I would like to add the result of a LINQ 2 SQL query to a label or textbox.
I use a class "CustomerClass" as a datalayer. In here I have a method with a LINQ query.
This result needs to be returned to the code behind file and added to a label or textbox.

Method in Class:

```
public static object SelectCustomerByUser(string user)
{
    var query = (from p in dc.Customers
                 where p.No_ == user
                 select p).Single();
    return query;
}
```

Code behind file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = Membership.GetUser().UserName.ToString().ToUpper();
    var queryresult = CustomerClass.SelectCustomerByUser(user);
    lblStreet.Text = ?????????

}
```

When i set the LINQ query direclty into the code behind file I can assign lblStreet.Text directly like: `lblStreet.Text = queryresult.Street`But I want to keep the LINQ queries separatly from the code behind file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `SelectCustomerByUser` returns a *boxed* object of *Customer* type so you need to `unbox` (type cast) it and assign properties/fields value to your user-interface.

Something like:

```
var queryresult = CustomerClass.SelectCustomerByUser(user) as Customer;
if(queryresult!=null)
  lblStreet.Text= queryresult.Street;
```

It would be better if you change the return type of `SelectCustomerByUser` and use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Single` method.

```
public static Customer SelectCustomerByUser(string user)
{
    var query = (from p in dc.Customers
                 where p.No_ == user
                 select p).Single();
    return query;
}
```

Comment: CustomerClass.SelectCustomerByUser(user) is already returning Customer object, so no need to type cast it again.

Comment: Take a look at return type of method in OP - `public static object SelectCustomerByUser(string user)`

Comment: Already had a look, Its public static Customer SelectCustomerByUser(string user) not public static object SelectCustomerByUser(string user). Please check your solution dear :) And also you haven't check for null values.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that the linq return an object from dc.Customers of type `CustomerClass`. You can create a function (something like `string GetCustomerStreet(){...}`), in order to polulate the label:

```
lblStreet.Text = ((CustomerClass)queryresult).GetCustomerStreet();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static CustomerClass SelectCustomerByUser(string user)
{
    var query = (from p in dc.Customers
                 where p.No_ == user
                 select p);
    if(query.Any())
    {
        var result=query.FirstOrDefault();
        return new CustomerClass
        {
            Id = result.Id,
            Name = result.Name,
            Age = result.Age
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = Membership.GetUser().UserName.ToString().ToUpper();
    var queryresult = CustomerClass.SelectCustomerByUser(user);
    lblStreet.Text = queryresult!=null?queryresult.Street:"";

}
```

OR

```
public static CustomerClass SelectCustomerByUser(string user)
{
    var query = (from p in dc.Customers
                 where p.No_ == user
                 select p);
    if(query.Any())
    {
        return query.FirstOrDefault();      
    }
    return null;
}
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = Membership.GetUser().UserName.ToString().ToUpper();
    var queryresult = CustomerClass.SelectCustomerByUser(user);
    lblStreet.Text = queryresult!=null?queryresult.Street:"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would let the function return a Customer instead of an object like:

```
public static Customer SelectCustomerByUser(string user)
```

Its a Customer class and the dunction is called `SelectCustomerByUser` it would make sence that it returns a customer, this will wnable you to access the members of a customer lie the street.

And you may consider using [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

assuming

```
var queryresult = CustomerClass.SelectCustomerByUser(user);
```

returns an instance of Customer, you can just cast it as that and then concatenate the properties into a string, or use a StringBuilder, whatever, like this:,

```
Customer c = (Customer)queryresult);
textbox.Text = String.Format("{0} email = {1}",customer.name , customer.email);
```

btw in the query I would do

```
select p).SingleOrDefault();
```

and then test the result for null before doing the cast